# Designing a custom listview row - need advice for positioning elements

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android

So here is the basic layout I'm after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s5oY.jpg

In the designer, I can't get the rectangle left-aligned how I want it.  Everything just overlaps.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkZoa.png

What would be the best way to lay this out?  I'm new and having a really tough time figuring out these layouts.  I'm using an extremely simple rectangle shape that I created in my drawables folder.

Any tips appreciated.. I'm really banging my head against the wall here.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_rectimage"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Some Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Some Description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds another nested LinearLayout but the performance loss should be negligible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_rectimage"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Some Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/row_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Some Description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest using `View` instead of `ImageView`.

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Not only did this answer my question but it helped me break up the UI into a format I'm comfortable with.. like nesting DIVs to section off UI elements on a website.